# Rewrite profile URL with username

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

In this code with `mod_rewrite` I can visit the profile of any user by typing his username after domain like **example.com/john** this will take us to john's profile. This works well however if I type any name which is not a username for existing user in my database like **example.com/notauser** I still get redirected to a empty profile page, though it has no profile pic or other info but all other buttons and links like followers, friends etc are still available. In such a case I want to redirected to login page or `echo` message user does not exist, but can't figure out how to do that.

`Profile.php`

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['username'])) { 
$username = $_GET['username'];
}
else if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { 
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else { 
header("Location: login.php"); 
die();
}
?>
```

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: It needs to be done at the time you try to fetch user-data.

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks i am so dumb it worked, you may answer this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to redirected to login page or `echo` message user does not
>   exist, but can't figure out how to do that.

Since the action depends on the factor that the user does not exist; you'll need to perform the redirection **after** you've tried to fetch data for the provided `$username`.